# Starting an app with a Tab View and no tabs selected?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing an iPhone app with Objective-C and iOS SDK with a tab view on the bottom.  I want to make the app so that when it first loads up, the tabs are on the bottom, but none of them are selected.  Instead, the user is presented with a "home" view, and can select the tabs from there if he / she desires.

How would I make this work?  I'm assuming it's something in the App Delegate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this recently.  Just do

```
[self.myTabBar setSelectedItem:nil];
```

Works perfectly, no tabs should be selected.  Let me know if you have any problems.  Also, just put that in either - (void) viewDidLoad or initWithNibName .

Comment: Hm.  I tried this, and I'm getting the warning: "UITabBarController may not respond to -setSelectedItem.".  I can do "setSelectedIndex, which let's me set the selected tab, but doesn't accept "nil" as a value.  Any ideas?

Comment: UITabBarController does not respond to setSelectedItem.  However, UITabBar does.  You can access that through your UITabBarController's tabBar property.  I did this without a UITabBarController in my app (I added a UITabBar to my UIView, made an outlet to the UITabBar, and did the code I pasted).

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be something that's appropriate to fake.

I would:

- Add a subview that overlays the area normally occupied by the selected tab view.
- Add UITabBarControllerDelegate tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController that will hide/remove that view.

The only remaining problem is to make the actually selected tab button seem unselected until the subview is hidden.